# Special characters issue

Tags: model-view-controller, c3.js

I am trying to convert encoded special symbols back to actual characters, but nothing is working.

I have tried following things
   Original text = "Test Update £ Coup é" but it is encoded to "Test Update � Coup�" when it is saved in Database.

I am trying to decode it while I am fetching the data.

```
string text="Test Update � Coup�";   
string decodedtxt = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
```

But it is not working, can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
string text="Test Update � Coup�";   
new MvcHtmlString(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text));
```